# Check if a user's rank equals any items in an array?

Tags: php

How would you check to see if a user's rank is equal to any rank in an array?

Example, say the user's rank is a moderator. I would check if the users rank equals any few ranks in an array.

```
//If only it were this easy..
$ranks = array('mod', 'admin');
    if($user_data['rank'] === $ranks) {
    //Do one thing
}
```

But the way I'm doing it, is:

```
if($user_data['rank'] === "mod" || $user_data['rank'] === "admin") {
    //Do one thing
}
```

How could I make this more efficient?

Comment: What you have now is pretty efficient; you're looking for something that's less code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in_array http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
$ranks = array('mod', 'admin');

if(in_array($user_data['rank'], $ranks)) {
    //Do one thing
}
```

Comment: @Epicballzy Note that in order for `in_array()` to perform `===` comparisons, you need to pass `true` as the third argument.